# PHP MYSQL search keywords

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a input field that search's for keywords in my database. Say the title of a car listing is "Toyota surf 1990 SSR-X", I want to be able to search something like "Toyota 1990", how can I achieve this?. If I search "Toyota surf" or "surf 1990" it works.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE title LIKE '%" . $search_keywords . "%'";
```

Comment: Look into fulltext search

Comment: well if year,make,model, etc are columns in that table(which would make sense for a table called cars?), you can build your where clause dynamically like: `WHERE make = 'Toyota' AND model = 'Surf'` or `WHERE model = 'surf' AND year = '1990'`

Comment: Notice: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/601300/3440545). [Always sanitize your database inputs](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE title LIKE '%" . $search_keywords .
>   "%'";

That code used in MySQL, so it doesn't have any relates with the main PHP coding.

Try using the **preg_match** feature instead.
Here is an example:

```
preg_match("KEYWORDS", $variable)
```

And you could add an **if** statement. Like the following:

```
if(preg_match("KEYWORDS", $variable))
```

I wish I could give you the solution that you are requesting for.